# Lua operations, that works in mutitheaded environment

Tags: multithreading, lua

My application uses **Lua** in **multithreaded** environment with *global mutex*. It implemented like this:

1. Thread locks mutex,
2. Call `lua_newthread`
3. Perform some initialization on `coroutine`
4. Run `lua_resume` on `coroutine`
5. Unlocks mutex

`lua_lock/unlock` is not implemented, GC is stopped, when lua works with `coroutine`.

My question is, can I perform steps 2 and 3 without locking, if initialisation process does not requires any global Lua structs? Can i perform all this process without locking at all, if `coroutine` does not requires globals too?

In what case I generally can use Lua functions without locking?

Answer (score 2):

Lua does not guarantee thread safety if you're trying to use **single** Lua state in **separate** OS threads without `lua_lock/unlock`. If you want to use multithreaded environment you need to use individual state for each OS thread.

Look at some multithreading solutions, e.g. https://github.com/effil/effil.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation.

Answer (score 1):

> In what case I generally can use Lua functions without locking?

On the same Lua state (or threads derived from the same source Lua state)?

***None.***

Lua is thread-safe in the sense that separate Lua state instances can be executed in parallel. There are absolutely no thread safety guarantees when you call *any* Lua API function from two different threads on the same Lua state instance.

You cannot do any of the steps 2, 3, or 4 outside of some synchronization mechanism to prevent concurrent access to the same state. It doesn't matter if it's just creating a new thread (which allocates memory) or some "initialization process" (which will likely allocate memory). Even things that don't allocate memory are still not allowed.

Lua offers no guarantees about thread-safety within a Lua state.